# How to Make a website for students to find their classmates before the school year begins

Tags: html, css, web-applications, backend

I am trying to make a website where people at my high-school, once we get our schedules, can input their classes and then the website would display whoever else inputted the same classes as them so they have an idea of who is going to be apart of their classes before the school year starts.

I've already done the html and CSS part of the website, however I'm not sure how to implement the primary function I desire. I know this is a very broad question and I am not very experienced in web design so if anyone could point me in the right direction I would be more than happy to read up on how to make this work. I know that this will require some back end work in which I don't know much about as I've only ever worked with the front end of website development. If there are any resources you guys could recommend to me that would be great!

I'm also new to using Stack Overflow so please let me know if I am doing something wrong. Thanks!

Comment: please show what you have got so far...

Comment: You need a database where to store whatever your users input. You need a form to allow people to input data into that database and you need some validation on that data (unless you want to allow random vandalism). Last, you need to a server-side "engine" that queries, compares, groups and displays database contents. To realize how general your question is, each of the above is outrageously general to ask on SO. A professional full-stack developer would need ~ 2 days to get this working with minimal functionality. I'd say it's a bit much for a beginner.

Comment: ... and, of course, the above applies in case you already have a public domain all set up and running for this thing (where people would come and add data) which, while not extremely complicated, sometimes proves to be a challenge for beginners.

Comment: Yeah I thought this was a bit too ambitious... oh well, thanks for answering at least! Maybe I'll change up my idea...